# iptables - how to make firefox think internet is un-plugged?

Tags: networking, centos, iptables

if I disconnect my internet and try to
lunch firefox..

in just 1 second firefox will stop 
trying to reach the internet and say
internet can not be reached.

okay.. now.. how can I do this same thing
with firefox

via iptables ?

in other words I will be connected to the
internet.

i want to launch firefox.

but iptables rules need to block all internet
and firefox needs to stop immediately
and say internet can not be reached.

currently.. with these iptables rules..

firefox will try to reach the internet
for about 10-20 seconds..
before it gives up and stops trying.

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables

*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j DROP
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -j DROP
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1):

You could stop the network interface to simulate your connectivity issues.

```
sudo ifdown eth0
```

Bring up the interface

```
sudo ifup eth0
```